# Adding additional Strings instead of overwriting existing String in MongoDB using Mongoose/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a patch Endpoint where I want to take the req.body from a form to add to a "Comments" field in my MongoDB Documents. Right now when I send a patch request the string overwrites the existing string in the Document Comments field but I would like an array of Strings to be the result. Is Patch the right solution, or is it Put? Do I need to change the Schema in Mongo to an array of Strings?

My Endpoint:

```
app.patch("/toilet/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params.id
  const update = { Comments: "Second Test Comment" };
  let toilet = await Toilet.findOneAndUpdate(id, update, {
    new: true
  });
  res.send(toilet)
})
```

The Schema:

```
const ToiletSchema = new Schema({
    Price:{
        type:String
    },
    Comments:[{
        type:String
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$push operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to append new comment to list of `Comments`.
Try changing this line:

```
const update = { $push: { Comments: "Second Test Comment" } };
```